# Snap to closest vertext in object mode goes to bounding box

Tags: snapping

My blender used to snap to vertex at closest to the object.
But suddenly it snapped to closest vertex from bounding box.
They said it is an expected behavior, but how to restore the behavior back to before?
i tried re installed it, back to default setting but nothing works
I used blender 2.8, 2.81
still the same

Answer (score 1):

There are settings in the snap dropdown as shown, make sure you have them set to what you want to snap to

[image: Snap settings]

Comment: well i've done that.

Here's what i found in developer.blender
https://developer.blender.org/T54300

The problem is, it's used to snap perfectly

Comment: Ah I see what you mean ... I don't know why they deem this expected behavior, it is clearly bad behavior.:(